# What's the difference among these wish sentences?

Tags: subjunctives

I would like to know the difference among the following sentences.

> 1. I wish I had a car.
> 2. I wish I would have a car.
> 3. I wish to have a car.

Comment: **I wish I would have a car*** is completely agrammatical in English and actually sounds uneducated. Don't try getting into a university using that....or getting a high-level job somewhere. It's marked as uneducated usage. "Hay los que saben, y los otros...."

Comment: @Lambie I don't know what to say I will probably just follow your advice and not use it at school or at work. I kind of see your point of view when I meditate on it, it sounds like if I'm reproaching my self for not having a car. Pero quien sabe, I might be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

In general, I wish + subject + past simple [is used to express wishes about the present.](http://www.myenglishpages.com/site_php_files/grammar-lesson-if-only.php) Therefore,

> I wish I had a car

means "I don't have a car. I want to have one."

2.

> I wish I would have a car.

means that you want to have a car sometime in the future.

Modals "would" and "could" [are used to express wishes about the future.](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/english-grammar/verbs/wishes-and-hypotheses) That type has the structure of:
I wish + subject + would/could + verb

3.

Now, honestly I haven't noticed the structure that is the same to your third example on any websites explaining the use of "I wish", that is probably because it's a more simple thing. It's just a regular sentence.
Considering that the verb "to wish" is used in present simple, and "to have" is an infinitive phrase that is serving as an adverb, it basically means that you right now in the present want to have a car.

Comment: i wish I had a car is the correct form. I wish I would have is a grammar mistake in English. I wish + subject + verb can take would or could. But not I wish + possession of a thing.

Comment: @Lambie can I say "I wish they left" instead of "I wish they would leave"?

Comment: @ManuelHernandez - That's a really good point!  If my cousins are here, and I want them to go away, I would say, **"I wish they would leave"** because we're talking about the future.  "I wish they left" isn't something I would usually say, and I can't really think of a good way that I'd ever use it.

Comment: How did you conclude "I wish I would have" is a grammar mistake? The source I listed above(when you click on hyperlink) says it's a proper thing to use, and I see nothing logically wrong with it. (Full sentence: I wish that I would have a car. I wish is the main clause, "that I would have a car" is the relative clause. Both are grammatically correct.)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/38759/discussion-on-answer-by-random-dude-whats-the-difference-among-these-wish-sente).

Answer (score -2):

/I wish I had a car/ is the correct form for wishing about something in the present. The verb wish should always be followed by the simple past: /I wish I spoke Chinese/ or /I wish I played golf/.

The reason for this is that you want something you do not or cannot have, the sentence is constructed like the IF hypothetical sentences: /If he were/was rich, he would be nicer./

/I wish I would have/ is incorrect in English. Always.

/I wish to have a [something] is correct but has a different meaning. It does  not mean you cannot have it. It is a  polite way of expressing something. For example, you might say (though it is old fashioned) to a waiter: /I wish to have the chicken dish/. Or you might say at a school when meeting with the principal: /My son wishes to learn Hindi./ In these two cases, wish means wants.

if the I wish is followed by subject + a verb as in: I wish they would leave. It's fine to use would. However, for possessing an object, it is not. I wish they would stop talking. Those are full sentences in fact (they is the subject and the verb is leave).

Comment: Be careful about saying "Always" so emphatically. I think "I wish I would have" is sometimes used to mean "I wish I had." _I wish I would have gone to college. I wish I would have talked to my mom more before she died. I wish I would have backed up the files on my computer before my hard drive crashed._ I think that's what might be going on [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22I+wish+I+would+have%22&safe=off&tbm=bks&prmd=ivns&start=20). (Note my downvote, btw)

Comment: No, J. R. **I wish I had gone to college** is grammatical in English. **I wish I would have gone is not grammatical**. That's exactly the type of thing they teach in remedial English in the first year of college for those who need it. I wish I HAD backed up my computer before my hard drive crashed.  You are just repeating over and over the TYPICAL mistakes made by so many. I'm flabbergasted that people here claim to be answering questions from English learners and are themselves so clueless. Sorry to be so harsh, but really, it's astounding.

Comment: English is like ice cream, it comes in many flavors: formal, conversational, colloquial, prescriptive, proper, literary, idiomatic, poetic, archaic, and slang. Not every learner is interested solely in dogmatic prescriptivism, and my link points to hundreds of counterexamples found in published books. (Read my comment carefully; I never said it was "grammatical".) As a footnote, keep your comments constructive. Astounded, flabbergasted, clueless? An English enthusiast like you should be able to comprehend these two words: [be nice](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: One has to learn the standards first, then criticize them ("interested in dogmatic prescriptivism"). Many learners have enough to take in without getting poor advice. One teaches the standard. Everything else comes after that. As a linguist, I uphold everyone's right to speak as they do whatever that may be, I do not judge at all. Au contraire. But, I don't teach "I'm gonna go" (for written Eng.) out the gate. Yes, English has many registers, and therefore, a learner would not be respected if told that a form is fine when it isn't in terms of baseline. Play jazz by all means, when you can.

Comment: I am polite yes. Did I say: "You are clueless"? I am flabbergasted and astounded (me).

Comment: You didn't call me clueless, but you implied much of the community is. And I wouldn't call "proof of how uneducated people are" a "polite" comment. To reiterate: Belittling language is not okay, be welcoming and patient, refrain from name-calling, don't be a jerk. (Sorry to be so harsh, but those aren't my words – I'm just quoting from the [SE model](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice)).

Comment: This is an English learners forums. I personally would not **dare** to pretend I knew how to explain English usage and grammar etc. unless I really knew it. My answer was shot down, one that is patently misinformed was voted up. Saying "I wish I would have" is actually semantically an impoverishment of meaning, not an enrichment of it. Perhaps it might be a good idea for those who aren't linguists to ponder that....

Comment: We agree that "I wish I had" is an improvement over "I wish I would have." That said, I thought your "always incorrect" assertion was a bit strong, and speculated that may have been a reason for the downvotes (though I have no idea who downvoted, or why). Still, as infuriating and flabbergastering as it might be to see what you perceive as an inferior answer get upvoted while yours gets downvoted, I don't think that calls for a wholesale indictment of the community. Anomalies happen.

Comment: I'd like to add some information, which I hope will be useful for the reader. But first off, I didn't downvote this question. I flagged one of the comments as nonconstructive, though. I don't think the answer is that bad, but it wasn't very good either. The first revision of this answer simply states */I wish I would have/ is incorrect in English. Always.* Nothing about *I wish they would leave*, which was added after the two downvotes (if I remember correctly), at all.

Comment: (cont.) Two potentially misleading points here: a) it was unclear which you meant in *I wish I would have* between *have* as an auxiliary verb and *have* as a main (i.e., lexical) verb, or perhaps it was meant for both; b) adding "Always" makes it sound like you're telling all learners that *I wish X would have (...?)* is always incorrect in English. (Note the patterns: *I wish X would* vs. *I wish I would*.) And that, in my humble opinion, is misleading. Maybe more serious than teaching "I'm gonna" since day one.

Comment: (cont.) In any case, at least you make it clear that *I wish they would leave* is fine. (I don't think you're clear about "why" it's fine "when" it's fine, though.) IMHO, one of the biggest problems a learner can have is false, incomplete, or misleading information. My last point, because you said "*I wish I would have gone* is not grammatical" and mentioned "Perhaps it might be a good idea for those who aren't linguists to ponder that..." You may find this paper interesting: [*“I Wish I Would Have Known!”*: The Usage of Would Have in ...](http://escholarship.org/uc/item/5wd0w3sz.pdf).

Comment: I wish takes either simple past or past perfect when there is a subject+ verb + a direct object. I wish he spoke Chinese. I wish you fried bananas. It's a counterfactual in the present. But an exception, with would expresses annoyance or impatience. Wish + would plus bare infinitive. I wish he would eat his dinner. So, "I wish you would have [drink]a beer" expresses annoyance or impatience. I wish I would have a car is wrong because the INTENDED meaning is: I wish I had one.